# What are the main differences among representations of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, and $GL(n,k)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What are the main differences among representations of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, and $GL(n,k)$? Here $k$ is a non-archimedean local field. Thank you very much.